Derivation of spinor Newman-Penrose equation
I am trying to work through the original paper by Newman-Penrose, Newman, E., & Penrose, R. (1962). An approach to gravitational radiation by a method of spin coefficients. Journal of Mathematical Physics, 3(3), 566-578.
I'm having trouble deriving the equation 3.14 in the paper, which is one of the main equations of NP formalism as it turns out. I have tried acting the commutator of derivatives on a basis spinor $\zeta_{cC}$, which results in,
$\begin{align*}
    \partial_{ed'}\partial_{ab'}\zeta_{cC}-\partial_{ab'}\partial_{ed'}\zeta_{cC} &= \Gamma^{A}_{aed'}\bar{\zeta}^{B'}_{b'}\Gamma_{CcAB'} + \zeta^A_a\bar{\Gamma}^{B'}_{b'ed'}\Gamma_{CcAB'}+\zeta^A_a\bar{\zeta}^{B'}_{b'}\zeta^E_e\bar{\zeta}^{D'}_{d'}\partial_{ED'}\Gamma_{CcAB'}\\
    &-\left( \Gamma^{E}_{eab'}\bar{\zeta}^{D'}_{d'}\Gamma_{CcED'} + \zeta^E_e\bar{\Gamma}^{D'}_{d'ab'}\Gamma_{CcED'} +\zeta^E_e\bar{\zeta}^{D'}_{d'}\zeta^A_a\bar{\zeta}^{B'}_{b'}\partial_{AB'}\Gamma_{CcED'}\right)
\end{align*}$
But I have no idea how to proceed further. As seen from the image 1, the final equation somehow includes Ricci and Weyl scalars, which I have no idea where they come from. Any help regarding the next step and the derivation would be great! Also if there are other better references to this formalism in the language of spinors please let me know.

Please type out equations rather than posting images!

Oh I thought the image is easier. Is there any particular reason for it? I'm new to posting questions here so just learning :)

@MattHanson I replaced the image with the equation as asked.

Is there any particular reason for it? Yes, there are several. See the accepted answer to this meta question.

@Ghoster Thanks I'll check it out
